# onPostExecute on IntentService

Tags: android, intentservice

Is there an IntentService version of AsyncTask's onPostExecute? I'm trying to send data from the IntentService and have it delivered into another Activity after IntentService finishes.

Comment: [Have you searched for a way yet?](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=send+data+from+intentservice+to+activity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there an IntentService version of AsyncTask's onPostExecute?

No, insofar as nothing is called on the main application thread after `onHandleIntent()` completes, other than `onDestroy()` (if there are no other queued commands to be processed).

> I'm trying to send data from the IntentService and have it delivered into another Activity after IntentService finishes.

One solution is to use `LocalBroadcastManager` or greenrobot's EventBus, as they will allow you to post an event from a background thread and have it be picked up by your UI layer on the main application thread.

You can achieve similar ends by lower-level mechanisms, such as a `Messenger` tied to a `Handler`, where the service sends a message via the `Messenger` to the `Handler`.

Comment: Thank you for this, probably saved me a lot of time and effort. I will look up LocalBroadcastManager.

Answer (score 0):

No.
You can Send Broascast for this. Register it in required activity.